# Google Firebase Event logging: how to see sequence of logged events

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-analytics

I have set up firebase analytics for my app including some custom events. Events are correctly displayed in the firebase console, and I can see for instance how many times an event has occurred in the specified time frame in total.

However, it would be interesting to see as well in what order these events are called to understand better how the user interacts with the app. Is there a way to display the occured events per user sessions. Or maybe even occured events in chronological order?

You can see this information in the realtime/debugview view and in crashlytics, but these are more specific use cases... Any advice would be welcomed!